# Error when using lua filename.lua

Tags: macos, lua, terminal

I'm very new to lua, and I've been trying to create a lua file using TextWrangler, then execute the file in my terminal (using a Mac).  I create the following in a textwrangler file:

```
for i=1,10 do
  print ("Hello")
    end
  print ("That's all!")
```

and I save it as test.lua.  I then move this file into the lua directory, `~/lua-5.2.3`.  I then start lua, and use the following command:

```
lua test.lua
```

and I get the following error:

> ```
> stdin: 1: syntax error near 'test'
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?  I've looked everywhere online for a solution to, what I assume, is a very simple oversight on my part, but I have found nothing.  My first thought was that I was putting the file in the wrong place, but I have moved it everywhere with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute script typing `lua test.lua` in terminal.

If you enter interpreter mode, you can use `dofile "test.lua"`. There is no lua command(function ) there, unless you declare it somewhere.

There is a [PIL section](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html) about stand-alone interpreter usage and more up-to date [reference section](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#7).

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I was trying to run lua, then load the file from the lua prompt, instead of going to the directory where the file is, and just using the normal terminal prompt to load it.  The link to the PIL section was the big helper.